# How to handle JSESSION ID from cookie in Angular2+ application?

Tags: javascript, java, angular

We are developing a stateful application. For this, In frontend, we are using Angular5 and at the back end Spring Rest. After successfully logged in, the server returns or set the JSESSION ID in a cookie. We have limited knowledge of Angular2.
As per our understanding, Angular has not provided an API to deal with cookie part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go through this link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service
It will help you out to find the cookie usage.

But cookie has some drawbacks you can try localstorage it's better.
Check out the link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-store